# Factory resetting a Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-tab

I haven't used my Galaxy Tab 3 in ages and would like to use it again, but it's not working as it used to. I would like to perform full system restore, but I'm having real problems.

Last month:

I press the On / Volume up / Start buttons to get to *MANUAL MODE*.

It gives me an option to do a factory reset, and says to use the volume buttons to get to this option.

I press to go down and it skips over the reset option, meaning I can't do it.

Today:

I press the On / Volume up / Start buttons and it crashes on *MANUAL MODE* saying:

```
-- Applying Multi-CSC...  
Applied the CSC-code : BTU  
Successfully appled multi-CSC.
```

How do I do a factory reset in another way?

Comment: If you have access to the OS, then the normal way should work? 1) Touch Settings.  2) Touch Privacy. 3) Touch Factory data reset. 4)Touch Reset device. 5)Touch Erase everything.  Of course, I assume you backed up everything already.

Comment: My bad. For the Tab3, it should be in the Accounts tab. Then Backup and Reset. I've recently had a Tab3 with lots of issues (crashing, etc.) and a factory reset solved it.

Comment: Yes, thank you - I found that. I'll run that a little later and hopefully this will clear everything. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to back up your data first if it has not been done. The standard way of resetting a Samsung Tab 3 tablet to factory is this:

1. From the Home screen touch Apps.
2. Touch Settings.
3. Touch the Accounts tab.
4. Touch Back up and reset.
5. Touch Factory data reset
6. Touch Reset device.
7. Touch Erase everything.

Please be advised that this erases everything on the tablet. Including history, documents, passwords, etc. Do not do this before making a backup if you have sensitive data on the tablet. Also, this will probably be different if you installed a custom OS. Refer to the documentation for said OS in that case.

Source: [How do I perform a factory reset on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3?](https://www.samsung.com/ie/support/mobile-devices/how-do-i-perform-a-factory-reset-on-my-samsung-galaxy-tab-3/)